# Paypal recurring profile related orders issue

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal-express, recurring

I have setup the Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout) payment method for the Magento version 1.7.0.2.

I have enabled the paypal billing agreement settings. When I try to place order with simple recurring product, it is creating new recurring profile for the customer which I can able to see in admin and customer my account section.

Issue I am facing is system is not generating any related order in Magento back-end. So I am not able to find any related orders for profile in admin as well in front-end.

I am using paypal sandbox account and I have also setup the IPN enabled for the paypal account.

Also, When I try to create order with new customer system creating new recurring profile but billing agreement is not generated in my account section. I am able to create it manually from my account billing agreement section.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion what should be an issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution, or figure out what the issue was?

Comment: This was just an IPN issue.  As per new Paypal security changes, server need ssl installed on it to work for IPN call. If your server have ssl installed and paypal call IPN, order will be automatically generate for the recurring orders.

Comment: See more details for paypal changed [here](https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-ssl-certificate-changes/)